# Webpack plugin for rails assets compatible manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, webpack

I'm trying to fully replace the rails asset pipeline with a webpack based pipeline. I've got the dev setup with the `webpack-dev-server` and hot reloading etc all working beautifully. Now what I'm trying to achieve is a compilation step for production that would mimic how rails compiles assets (digesting / generating a compatible manifest.json file) such that I can still use helpers like `javascript_include_tag` etc. This is where I'm stuck.

I've read lots of tutorials on using webpack with rails, but they all end up writing their own view helpers to load the assets. I'm trying to avoid this because I don't want extra overhead or for devs to need to understand a different pipeline. I also want config like `asset_host=` to work out of the box for using a CDN etc.

Ultimately, what I want is something similar to [gulp-rev-rails-manifest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-rails-manifest) that generates a rails-asset-pipeline compatible manifest file on compilation, but I haven't found a plugin (yet) that exists for Webpack. So...

1. is it possible to run a webpack build through a gulp stream *using webpack only* (ie not using gulp-webpack) so I can use the above gulp plugin. The reason I don't want to use gulp-webpack is that it takes over your entries / output etc and I find that whole setup confusing since this all already exists in `webpack.config`

Or

2. Does anyone have any decent resources on writing plugins for Webpack. It seems a bit of a black box to me and the official site has a menu section for "How to write a plugin" but it's not actually a link to anything.

Or

3. Is there actually a plugin that will do exactly this and I don't know how to search properly on the interwebs.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've released webpacked gem to integrate webpack into Rails app + zero config hot module replacement. Check out docs for more info: https://github.com/Darkside73/webpacked

Answer (score 2):

Running webpack in a gulp task is [very simple](http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

gulp.task('webpack', function(done) {
  webpack(webpackConfig, function(err, stats) {
    done(err);
  });
});
```

Note that the [`stats`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#stats) object provided to the webpack callback contains information about all assets emitted by webpack, so you could potentially use it to generate your own manifest.

Here are a few webpack plugins you might find useful:

- https://github.com/sporto/assets-webpack-plugin
- https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin
- https://github.com/diurnalist/chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin

While there is no official tutorial on how to create a plugin, there's still a [Plugin API](http://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html) doc that describes the different interfaces your plugins can hook into. The [webpack source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) and github contain a lot of webpack plugin examples.

Here's a very simple plugin that just logs assets:

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.plugin('done', function(stats) {
    console.log(stats.toJson().assets);
  });
};
```

Comment: As mentioned that's exactly what I DON'T want. I don't want to run gulp. I'd like it to all just be done through the webpack build command.

Comment: @brad See the bottom half of my answer. Also, your post mentioned not using `gulp-webpack` in particular, hence my first suggestion.